# What GHC/Haskell specification says that free type constructors match rightmost types?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-variables, type-kinds, type-constructor

I was caught off guard recently when I tried to pass a constructor for a type of kind `* -> * -> *`, with one bound type var, to a function expecting a constructor for `* -> *`. Concretely, it was along the lines of passing `(\x -> (x, 42)) :: (forall a. a -> (a, Int))` to a function of type `forall c. (forall a. a -> c a) -> ...`. This is ambiguous but not an error in GHC: `(,)` cast to `* -> *` could be interpreted as a constructor for either the left or righthand argument, and GHC appears to just default to the righthand argument. For higher-kinded matches, it'll take the right*most* arguments. To see this, just test the inferred type:

```
foo :: c a b -> a -> b -> ()
foo _ _ _ = ()

bar = foo ((), 42, 'a') 42 'a' -- typechecks
```

I wrongly believed instead that it would match the free variables in order, but this higher-rank case is the only time where that would obviously be preferred, and other times it's a wash. Is there official documentation describing this rule? I'm slightly annoyed but also understanding of the fact that this is not an error, because I can foresee that saves wrapping a lot of things in newtypes.

Comment: Note that `(a,b)` is syntactic sugar for `(,) a b`, while `(a,b,c)` is syntactic sugar for `(,,) a b c`, and so on. Even `a -> b` is shorthand for `(->) a b`, and `[a]` is sugar for `[] a`. Hence, all these types are of the form `T arg1 ... argn` for some type constructor `T`.

Comment: Specifically, `c` is the partial application of `(,,)` to `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the question, this simply follows from type application being left-associative, just like function application.

`(a, b)` is `(,) a b` is `((,) a) b`. So `(Int, a)` is `((,) Int) a`, but `(a, Int)` isn't `<something> a`.